# Hosting management

Tags: hosting

I'm looking for a tool that lets me keep record of which servers I have, domain names, ip ranges, etc. Does anyone know of a tool that does all this? Could be either web-based or desktop (non-windows).

Update: I'm not about to start a hosting company, we outsource all our hosting. We just need the tool to keep track of our servers/ip ranges etc and do not have the time to test a lot of software because we are on a time constraint.

Comment: Seirous? this is an established market with a dozen or so established commercial products (and some open source ones). Maybe you should consider doing some research before working in an area? ;)

Comment: In general,. webhostingtalk.com is a good place to start knowing that hosting is more than putting a server in a rack.

Comment: Well actually this is not our core business and born out of necessity. I've done my research but i do not have the time to test alot of software. So thats why i turn to the people who use it on a day-to-day basis. I know how hosting works, However -- we outsource EVERY little bit of the hosting, we just need the tool to keep track of our stuff. Thats why i'm asking this question.

Comment: @Stephen 3 out of your 4 Questions have negative scores, half were closed, half deleted... The one open question is borderline shopping as well. [SF] is *for System Administrators*. It is not *get free helpdesk from a pro*. Please have a look at [SU] and [Unix.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a configuration management database?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management_database

Try http://www.cmdbuild.org/en/